# How fix error Endpoint not found WCF REST POST

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, post

I have a WCF REST service with string as input,

IService.cs:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceImportAutoLiasse
{   
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]     
    string PostJson(string request);
}
```

IService.svc.cs:

```
  public string PostJson(string request)
    {
    //...
    }
```

And I verify the web.config , it is well done:

```
 <services>
  <!--SOAP-->
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehavior" name="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.Service">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingCongHttp"
      contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />

    <!--REST-->
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBhavior" bindingConfiguration="BindingConfigWebHttp"
     binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SysLap.Services.Web.ImportAutoLiasse.IService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

And I test it with POSTMAN:

```
https://localhost:44355/ServiceImportAutoLiasse.svc/rest/PostJson
```

with the JSON input :

```
{
"Headers": ["Header":"CA","Header":"Pe","Header":"RU","Header":"P_AMOUNT"],
"Values": ["value":"A;2019.12;S200;100","value":"A;2019.12;S000;1" ]
}
```

And I have error:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error
        deserializing the object of type System.String. End element 'root' from namespace '' expected. Found element
        'Headers' from namespace ''.'. See server logs for more details
```

- And when I test with a browser :

  https://localhost:44355/ServiceImportAutoLiasse.svc/rest/help/operations/PostJson

I get error: "Endpoint not found."

How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you posted, we should change the `ContentType` if the operation only accepts `String`. But if you want to pass a strong-type object parameter via JSON data, you could refer to the below code snippets.
Assumed that there is a below data contract,

```
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
}
```

And a service contract,

```
        [OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]   
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
```

Then we could test the operation by constructing a below request.
[image]
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand very well now the issue

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, in fact I must deactivate Content-Type in Headers in POSTMAN:

[image]

And now it works very well,